# Android Java Not Updating DynamoDB Table Using Table.updateItem()?

Tags: java, android, amazon-dynamodb

So my table currently has this item with 7 columns.*user_id* is the primary key.

[image: table]

I do the following to get the current row and update that row with a new List column called "heart_rate_info" added.

```
    Document newMeasurement = new Document();
    newMeasurement.put("time_ms", model.getTime_ms());
    newMeasurement.put("session_id", model.getSession_id());

    Primitive primitive_user_id = new Primitive(user_id);
    Document currentDoc = userTable.getItem(new Primitive(user_id));
    Document result;
    if(model.getDataType()== MeasurementModel.SENSORS.HEART){
        newMeasurement.put("heart_rate_frequency", model.getRaw_measurement());
        if(currentDoc.get("heart_rate_info")!=null){
            DynamoDBList heart_rate_info = currentDoc.get("heart_rate_info").asDynamoDBList();
            heart_rate_info.add(newMeasurement);
            currentDoc.put("heart_rate_info", heart_rate_info);
            result = userTable.updateItem(currentDoc, primitive_user_id,
                    new UpdateItemOperationConfig().withReturnValues(ReturnValue.UPDATED_NEW));
        }else{
            DynamoDBList heart_rate_info = new DynamoDBList();
            heart_rate_info.add(newMeasurement);
            currentDoc.put("heart_rate_info", heart_rate_info);
            result = userTable.updateItem(currentDoc,
                    new UpdateItemOperationConfig().withReturnValues(ReturnValue.UPDATED_NEW));
        }
    }
```

When I run the program in debug mode, I can see that it grabs the right row and updates *currentDoc* with the correct *heart_rate_info* data. The problem is when I run

```
result = userTable.updateItem(currentDoc,
                    new UpdateItemOperationConfig().withReturnValues(ReturnValue.UPDATED_NEW));
```

This returns an empty result. It's not a null value, it doesn't throw an error. Just returns an empty result and the table does not get updated. I'm not completely sure what's going on.

This is *currentDoc* when I call userTable.get

[image]

This is *currentDoc* right before userTable.updateItem is called.

[image]

```
userTable.putItem 
userTable.getItem
```

Both work so why won't updateItem work. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert on this Java API, but looking at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/JavaDocumentAPIItemCRUD.html#JavaDocumentAPIItemUpdate it seems that `updateItem` does not do what you think it does:

If you want to just replace the old item with the new one, use the `putItem` operation, not `updateItem`. With `updateItem` the old item just determines the **key** of the item, and then you are supposed to use an `UpdateExpression` to say what gets updated and how. This expression isn't simply an entire new item - see the documentation for its syntax.

Because you didn't give any update expression, the item wasn't updated at all, so the `UPDATED_NEW` returned only the attributes which the update modified - i.e., nothing.

Comment: Using putItem fixed it! Thanks!